# How to stop SimpleCV camera stream?

Tags: python, camera, simplecv

I'm trying to learn SimpleCV using Python 2.7 in IDLE.

Once the camera form SimpleCV is initialized the camera become unavailable to other programs like native webcam application or skype etc.

```
from SimpleCV import *
camera = Camera()
```

After restarting the pc or logoff and logon the webcam becomes to those applications. It seems that even closing out from python IDLE, it doesn't close the camera stream. Is there any way to stop the camera stream of `simplecv`?

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to be able to duplicate the issue? The webcam shuts off for me when I close IDLE. Regardless, as a quick fix, you can go to the task manager and manually close any open Python processes after closing IDLE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your way is an option but shouldn't be there any convenient way to close the stream in the code while the camera isn't being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't replicate your issue, but if the webcam is still running even after your program terminates/you close IDLE, you can end the camera by going into task manager and killing all running Python processes.

After some experimenting, I found that if you want to accomplish the same thing directly inside the code, you could try simply deleting the reference altogether:

```
>>> import SimpleCV as scv
>>> cam = scv.Camera()
>>> del cam
```

Calling `del cam` caused the webcam indicator light on my laptop to turn off. Granted, this appears to be an undocumented (??) solution, so I'm not sure how robust it is. I would probably try testing this on several different laptops/webcams first, to make sure it works reliably and consistently.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either - running SimpleCV 1.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This solution does toggle the light on my webcam off (Logitech c270), leading me to think that this solution does work.